# How to avoid long integer during date extraction using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below. This is a continuation of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68313571/elegant-way-to-write-np-where-for-different-values-in-a-column)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [101,101,101,101,202,202,202],
                   'person_type':['A','A','B','C','D','B','A'],
                   'login_date':['5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM','09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM','06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM','06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM','12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM','13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM','13/12/2012 11:45:00 AM'],
                   'logout_date':[np.nan,'11/08/2013 11:21:00 AM',np.nan,'06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM',np.nan,'13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM',np.nan]})
df.login_date = pd.to_datetime(df.login_date)
df.logout_date = pd.to_datetime(df.logout_date)
```

I would like to apply 2 rules to the logout_date column

Rule 1 - If person type is B, C,D,E AND logout_date is NaN, then copy the login date value

Rule 2 - If person type is A AND logout_date is NaN, then add 2 days to the login date

When I try the below

```
m1 = df['person_type'].isin(['B','C','D'])
m2 = df['person_type'].isin(['A'])
m3 = df['logout_datetime'].isna()

df['logout_datetime'] = np.select([m1 & m3, m2 & m3],
                              [df['login_datetime'], df['login_datetime'] + pd.DateOffset(days=2)],
                               default=df['logout_datetime'])
df['logout_date'] = np.select([m1 & m3, m2 & m3],
                              [df['login_datetime'].dt.date, (df['login_datetime'] + pd.DateOffset(days=2)).dt.date],
                               default=df['logout_datetime'])
```

I would like to get the `logout_date` column directly by using `np.select` as shown in sample code.

Currently I get an output like below which is incorrect

[image]

I don't understand why some rows are causing issues while other rows are working fine.

Can help me with this? I expect my output to have proper date values

Comment: yes, logout data can have `na`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is missing converting in `default` parameter in `np.select` (`default=df['logout_datetime']`) and change it to `default=df['logout_datetime'].dt.date` for same types returned from `np.select`:

```
df['logout_date'] = np.select([m1 & m3, m2 & m3],
                              [df['login_date'].dt.date, 
                              (df['login_date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=2)).dt.date],
                               default=df['logout_date'].dt.date)
print (df)
   person_id person_type          login_date logout_date
0        101           A 2013-05-07 09:27:00  2013-05-09
1        101           A 2013-09-08 11:21:00  2013-11-08
2        101           B 2014-06-06 08:00:00  2014-06-06
3        101           C 2014-06-06 05:00:00  2014-06-06
4        202           D 2011-12-11 10:00:00  2011-12-11
5        202           B 2012-10-13 00:00:00  2012-10-13
6        202           A 2012-12-13 11:45:00  2012-12-15
```

If need `default` with datetimes then [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) remove times (set to `00:00:00`) and all types are `datetime`s, so working well:

```
df['logout_date'] = np.select([m1 & m3, m2 & m3],
                              [df['login_date'].dt.normalize(), 
                               (df['login_date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=2)).dt.normalize()],
                               default=df['logout_date'])
print (df)
   person_id person_type          login_date         logout_date
0        101           A 2013-05-07 09:27:00 2013-05-09 00:00:00
1        101           A 2013-09-08 11:21:00 2013-11-08 11:21:00
2        101           B 2014-06-06 08:00:00 2014-06-06 00:00:00
3        101           C 2014-06-06 05:00:00 2014-06-06 05:00:00
4        202           D 2011-12-11 10:00:00 2011-12-11 00:00:00
5        202           B 2012-10-13 00:00:00 2012-10-13 00:00:00
6        202           A 2012-12-13 11:45:00 2012-12-15 00:00:00
```

For origional datetimes use:

```
df['logout_date'] = np.select([m1 & m3, m2 & m3],
                              [df['login_date'], 
                               (df['login_date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=2))],
                               default=df['logout_date'])
print (df)
   person_id person_type          login_date         logout_date
0        101           A 2013-05-07 09:27:00 2013-05-09 09:27:00
1        101           A 2013-09-08 11:21:00 2013-11-08 11:21:00
2        101           B 2014-06-06 08:00:00 2014-06-06 08:00:00
3        101           C 2014-06-06 05:00:00 2014-06-06 05:00:00
4        202           D 2011-12-11 10:00:00 2011-12-11 10:00:00
5        202           B 2012-10-13 00:00:00 2012-10-13 00:00:00
6        202           A 2012-12-13 11:45:00 2012-12-15 11:45:00
```

Comment: Even if I don't use `dt.date` for the default value, it should only fill by datetime value right? Wwhy does it fill with an interger?..upvited

Comment: @TheGreat - because there is mismatch with `date`s and `datetime`s

Comment: @TheGreat - `df['login_date'].dt.date` return dates, then `(df['login_date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=2)).dt.date` return `date`s and `default=df['logout_date']` return datetimes

Comment: For the default value of df['logout_datetime'], instead of retaining actual value `2014-06-06 08:00:00`, it makes it to `2014-06-06 00:00:00`

Comment: @TheGreat - need ouput like second paragraph answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234812/discussion-between-the-great-and-jezrael).